# Cannot log in to user root

Tags: mysql, xampp, root

I've gotten a new laptop and after installing the newest version of xampp I cant log in to mysql as -u root. 
I made sure that mysql is turned on in xampp.
Lines I've tried
cd\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql.exe -u root -p
cd\xampp\mysql\bin -u root -p 
I've also tried starting mysql.exe directly and couldnt log in with similair commands.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the database with a database management tool, or connecting via a web script to verify that you can connect in other ways?

Comment: No I haven't. I don't have any databases saved on this computer. How would I go about checking it in other ways.

Comment: Personally I would download MySQL workbench (http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) and then set up a connection using that.  You'll also be able to administer the database (create schemas, add tables, check queries etc.) with that.  It's not the best out there, but it's good for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default setup of Xampp does not set a root password in mysql.

Try connecting without the -p. c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe --user=root

The following is from the FAQ - https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_windows.html

> Is XAMPP production ready?
>
> Here a list of missing security in XAMPP:
>
> The MySQL administrator (root) has no password.

Comment: In mysql.exe I get an ERROR 42000 which says that -u isnt a command and in cmd it can't find the specified route

Comment: In cmd i have tried cd\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql.exe -u root -p and the same without >mysql.exe   and in mysql.exe i have tried -u root -p as well as -u root

Comment: i believe on windows you need to run it like this: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe --user=root

Comment: windows cannot find the path specified